# Relationship between Alnum and IsAlphabetic character classes in Java RegEx patterns

Tags: java, regex, unicode, posix

Looking at the [Javadoc for java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> `\p{Alnum}`   An alphanumeric character:`[\p{IsAlphabetic}\p{IsDigit}]`

it appears that every character that matches `\p{IsAlphabetic}` should also match `\p{Alnum}`

However, it does not seem to be the case when the character has an accent. For example, the following assertion fails:

```
assertEquals("é".matches("\\p{IsAlphabetic}+"),"é".matches("\\p{Alnum}+"));
```

The same thing happens for other characters with accents such as `ą`, `ó`, `ł`, `ź` `ż`. All match `\p{IsAlphabetic}+` but not `\p{Alnum}+`

Am I mis-interpreting the Javadoc? Or is this a bug in the documentation or implementation?

Comment: `\p{Alnum}` only matches ASCII letters and digits. Use `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option to make it fully Unicode aware.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that did the trick. Thanks very much!

Comment: If you read the documentation page you referenced, you will see that `\p{Alnum}` = `[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]` and `\p{Alpha}` = `[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]` and `\p{Lower}` = `[a-z]` and `\p{Upper}` = `[A-Z]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `\p{Alnum}` is treated as a POSIX character class which means it will only ever match ASCII characters. This means it will match `a` and `1` but not `ä` or `١`.

The passage you quote only applies when the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag is used.

Slightly oversimplified, this flag will turn the "old" POSIX style character classes into their equivalent Unicode character classes.

Comment: It's actually right there in the docs but the way it's worded,I didn't get it on the first read. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Your quote from the documentation is fine **but** you missed to read the line before that table:

> The following **Predefined Character classes** and **POSIX character classes** are in conformance with the recommendation of *Annex C: Compatibility Properties* of [*Unicode Regular Expression*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/), **when `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is specified.**

If you read the documentation page you referenced, you will see that `\p{Alnum}` = `[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]` and `\p{Alpha}` = `[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]` and `\p{Lower}` = `[a-z]` and `\p{Upper}` = `[A-Z]`.

So, `\p{Alnum}` only matches ASCII letters (and digits) when `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is not set while `\p{L}` (=`\p{IsAlphabetic}`) matches all Unicode letters by default (no flag is necessary).